# Finalizar 10 seg. antes, la reproducción de audio

Tags: javascript

En este ejemplo quiero mostrar como mediante **x.currentTime = 10;** el audio toma la posición de 10 segundos y empieza a reproducirse justo desde ese punto. Mi pregunta es, ¿como se puede hacer al revés, que el audio termine 10 segundos antes?, ya que no encontrado documentación al respecto. Agradecido de antemano por vuestra paciencia y sabiduría.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
function getCurTime() { 
  alert(x.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() { 
  x.currentTime = 10;
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/469/469273_4397472-lq.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio><br>

<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Establecer la posición de inicio a 10 segundos</button>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Los elementos [*media* (audio y video) tienen el atributo `duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), que puedes usar para calcular lo que quieres:

Por otro lado, tenes el evento `timeupdate`, que se lanza cada vez que `currentTime` es actualizado por el navegador.

He cogido tu ejemplo, he hecho que con el botón vaya a 15 segundos del final y luego he puesto un *event listener* para que se pare 5 segundos después, a ver si te sirve.

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
function setCurTime() { 
  audio.currentTime= audio.duration - 15;
}

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
  if (audio.currentTime > (audio.duration - 10)) {
    audio.pause();
    console.log('Pausado!');
  }
});
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/469/469273_4397472-lq.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio><br>

<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Establecer la posición de inicio a 15 segundos del final</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! Gracias!!!